# Include quotes and apostrophe in labels using DiagrammeR

Tags: r, quotes, diagrammer

I'm trying to include an apostrophe in a label of a node in a `DagrammeR` graph using `grViz`. Let's say that I want to create the label `"Peter's car"`. The problem is that DiagrammeR does not seem to accept double quotes (`""`) so, when I use single quotes `'Peter's car'` it does not work because the apostrophe escapes the whole thing.

I have tried using `\` or `\\`, but nothing seems to work.

```r
library("DiagrammeR")
graph <- "
digraph names { 
graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

node [shape = box,
        fontname = Helvetica,
        fontsize = 10]
  1 [label = 'Peter\\'s car']
  2 [label = 'Peter\'s Car']

1 -> 2
}
"
grViz(graph)
```

The graph is just for testing. It does not convey any meaning.

I would expect to see in the note the label "peter's car" (without the double quotes)

Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe you could use Unicode: 'Peter&rsquo;s car'

Comment: If you use `label = <\"Peter's Car\">` it works in raw graphviz.
However, `grViz` has the line `diagram <- gsub(x = diagram, "'", "\"")`
which swaps out the single quotation. If you comment out this line in the `grViz` code it works the same as `graphviz`.

Comment: Dear @BenNutzer, your solution works very well. However, it is super verbose.

Comment: @user20650, thank you for the solution. Could not it be the case that the line you mention has another purpose so that by commenting it, I might be breaking an important functionality?

Comment: @R.AndresCastaneda ; yup im sure it does have a reason but it may be as minimal a reason as converting the outer quotes to doubles. Do note that either quote type is fine in graphviz. You can test with an example: set the labels as above e.g. `1 [label = <\"Peter's car\">]`, then remove offending line
`body(grViz)[[4]] = quote('')`, and then run `grViz(graph)`. This works fine for this example. You can the reset the function using `grViz <- DiagrammeR::grViz`.